# How to get output in JAXB (marshaling)?

Tags: java, jaxb, marshalling

I tried hello world example from [here](http://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/section_1_3-Hello-World.html#Hello%20World) and I can't see any output in my program (in console when using "java" command). Is it something wrong I do? The code of marshal function looks like this:

```
public void marshal() {
    try {
        JAXBElement<GreetingListType> gl =
            of.createGreetings( grList );
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance( "hello" );
        Marshaller m = jc.createMarshaller();
        m.marshal( gl, System.out );
    } catch( JAXBException jbe ){
        // ...
    }
}
```

I tried also tried to put output into a file like this:

```
public void marshal() {
    try {
        JAXBElement<GreetingListType> gl =
            of.createGreetings( grList );
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance( "hello" );
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("plik.xml");
        Marshaller m = jc.createMarshaller();
        //m.marshal( gl, System.out );
        m.marshal(gl, fos);
        fos.close();
    } catch( JAXBException jbe ){
        // ...
    }
  catch( IOException ioe ){
    // ...
}
}
```

but it didn't work out. Have you got any solutions?

EDIT: After printing Stack Trace it gave me this, looks promising:

```
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: "hello" doesnt contain ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:186)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:148)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:310)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:392)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:357)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:264)
    at Hello.marshal(Hello.java:28)
    at Hello.main(Hello.java:43)
```

I do have ObjectFactory but don't know anything about jaxb.index. Is it necessary? How it should look like?

Comment: What is the problem (the exception)? Which output do you expect? We need more details.

Comment: I would recommend putting jbe.printStackTrace(); in the catch block...

Comment: I'd love to see any efect - in console when i execute it using java command or in XML file. I'm not even sure how it should work in example (it's not written)

Comment: Did you use the same xml schema to generate `GreetingListType`?

Comment: yes, it was generated using one xjc command on schema presented in tutorial. Should it write in console by itself?

Comment: The problem is in the demo (http://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/section_1_3-Hello-World.html#Hello%20World), I have included a corrected version in my answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682959/how-to-get-output-in-jaxb-marshaling/6683362#6683362.

Comment: Blaise Doughan, yes thanks, it's correct but it still produced exception code. Is it helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The demo appears to be incomplete (missing main method):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Hello hello = new Hello();
    hello.make("FOO", "BAR");
    hello.marshal();
}
```

Below is the corrected version:

```
package hello;

import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Hello {

    private ObjectFactory of;
    private GreetingListType grList;

    public Hello(){
        of = new ObjectFactory();
        grList = of.createGreetingListType();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Hello h = new Hello();
        h.make( "Bonjour, madame", "fr" ); 
        h.make( "Hey, you", "en" ); 
        h.marshal();    }

    public void make( String t, String l ){
        GreetingType g = of.createGreetingType();
        g.setText( t );
        g.setLanguage( l );
        grList.getGreeting().add( g );
    }

    public void marshal() {
        try {
            JAXBElement<GreetingListType> gl =
                of.createGreetings( grList );
            JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance( "hello" );
            Marshaller m = jc.createMarshaller();
            m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
            m.marshal( gl, System.out );
        } catch( JAXBException jbe ){
            // ...
        }
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Greetings>
   <Greeting language="fr">
      <Text>Bonjour, madame</Text>
   </Greeting>
   <Greeting language="en">
      <Text>Hey, you</Text>
   </Greeting>
</Greetings>
```

Comment: I pasted the code in the file with jbe.printStackTrace(); in the catch block. It gave me error I'll post in question.

Comment: And it has main method from tutorial page, so it's ok :)

Comment: @GoMati - I don't see a `main` method in the example:  http://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/section_1_3-Hello-World.html#Hello%20World

Comment: You are absolutely right, and I added it. Unfortunately it didn't produce any results, but I posted what happenned jbe.printStackTrace(); in my question. Maybe it'll narrow out what is really happening?

Comment: @GoMati - What is in your "hello" package?  You should have:  "GreetingListType", "GreetingType", and "ObjectFactory".

Comment: yes, and I do compile them with "javac ./hello/Hello.java" command, it compiles all 4 files (3 you posted and Hello.java to Hello.class) - how should I run it to make it work?

Comment: Ok, it had the package problem, now it works just GREAT. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 3):

I came across the same problem.  Turns out that you need to change this line:

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance( "hello" );
```

but placing the actual full package in which you generated your files:

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance( "my.generated.package.etc" ); // or whatever.
```

Comment: Thanks.. this worked for me too. Actually the complete packge name should be passed in newInstance method.